# Converting Python dictionary using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following Python dictionary:

```
{
 "cat": 1,
 "dog": 1,
 "person": 2,
 "bear": 2,
 "bird": 3
}
```

I would like to use dictionary comprehensions to convert it to the following dictionary:

```
{
 1 : ["cat", "dog"],
 2 : ["person", "bear"],
 3 : ["bird"]
}
```

How can I go about doing this in a one liner?

Comment: If you want any sort of aggregation, it turns out a dict comprehension is almost always a terrible fit. Dict comprehensions require you to specify a key's value in one expression, but doing that is clumsy and inefficient for aggregation.

Comment: Please don't. This isn't a problem that should be solved in a single line.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Python is a popular language for code golf challenges. There are also circumstances where the size of your source code can matter (micro computers). Day to day, this might be a bad idea, but maybe OP has a legitimate use case for it.

Comment: @mypetlion If the byte count matters, they should ask for a short solution. Asking for a dict comprehension solution is really just asking for a bad solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not efficient as this is not how dicts are intended to be used, but you can do the following

```
d = {"cat": 1, "dog": 1, "person": 2, "bear": 2, "bird": 3}

new = {v: [i[0] for i in d.items() if i[1] == v] for v in d.values()}
```

Comment: This works but is kind of inefficient for large dictionaries since you go through the data O(n^2) times. +1 for cleverness though.

Comment: I preferred this solution because it's easier to read and efficiency is not a concern in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = {
...  "cat": 1,
...  "dog": 1,
...  "person": 2,
...  "bear": 2,
...  "bird": 3
... }
>>> 
>>> b = {}
>>> for key, value in a.items():
...     if value not in b:
...         b[value] = [key]
...     else:
...         b[value].append(key)
... 
>>> print(b)
{1: ['cat', 'dog'], 2: ['person', 'bear'], 3: ['bird']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a one-liner:

```
import itertools
d = {'person': 2, 'bird': 3, 'dog': 1, 'bear': 2, 'cat': 1}
new_d = {a:[i for i, _ in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])}
```

Output:

```
{1: ['cat', 'dog'], 2: ['person', 'bear'], 3: ['bird']}
```